# Deploy Contract that Imports Other Contracts in Mist

Tags: solidity, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have a main smart contract that Imports two other contracts by their file path. Inside the contract I have:

Import "/test/files/test.sol"
Import  "/test/files/testimport.sol"

So I have three contracts in total. The main contract uses modifiers and mappings from the other two contracts.

How do I deploy these contracts in Mist while allowing the main contract to communicate with the other two imported contracts?

If this cannot be done in Mist, what is the best way to deploy these contracts so they can communicate?

Comment: Compile the contract with `solc`. It will include everything in the bytecode. Use the ABI and bytecode to deploy your contract. But without seeing your contract code it's hard to tell what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: Here is a link to my code with another question attached: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38811/how-would-i-make-this-contract-upgradable